# How to read two strings and array of numbers from a file and store them in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a simple structure in my code to read the values from a txt file. 
this struct is

```
struct read_data_into_file{
std::string Fname,Lname;
double score[5];
double sum;
};
```

then I have a function to open and read from the file.

```
void ReadFromFile(){
std::ifstream f;
read_data_into_file Newobj;
std::vector<read_data_into_file> obj;
f.open("/Users/vibhorsagar/Desktop/cslabs/cs-116lab1/cs-116lab1/input.txt");
if(!f.is_open())
{
    std::cout<<"error opening file";

}
else{
    while(!f.eof())
    {
        f>>Newobj.Fname>>Newobj.Lname;
        for(count=0;count<5;count++)
        {
        f>>Newobj.score[count];
            Newobj.sum+=Newobj.score[count];
        }
        obj.push_back(Newobj);
    }
        for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++){
        std::cout<<obj[i]<<" "<<std::endl;

    }
}
f.close();
```

I am kinda confused on how to read the data in the vector. The text file contains a bunch of names and numbers.

Andria Senger 80 65 81 76

Nathalie Witherspoon 96 99 93

Maribel Danner 94 53 96 91 60

Kara Hogan 52 75 93 97 95

Elliot Kremer 74 50 96 68

Keena Scheurer 100 90 57 97 90

Sindy Morfin 74 67

Janeth Saito 81 60 60

These are the contents of the txt file. I was thinking I could store individual name as a first name and a last name and the numbers after that into an array. and then find their individual average. but when I try to print the vector in the function I get an error

Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'std::__1::__vector_base >::value_type' (aka 'read_data_into_file'))

Also the numbers in each line are not 5, but I am using that for the array size because that was the highest number in a line. I don't know how to dynamically set the array size for each line. 
I am using Xcode on Mac to write and compile.

if there is any other way to do this, I can use the help or if you can suggest a better way to do this. Thank You!

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::vector` and read it. that's how you handle different number of values in each record. As far as your error goes, C++ does not have an operator for printing out the whole array, at once. You have to write a loop that prints one value at a time, from the array.

Comment: okay, but how do I read the numbers in the file as an array and output in on the console. there isn't really anything related to that in the book.

Comment: Use a vector to store the scores, and just push each score read into it. You are best to use getline to read each line as a string then read the various fields from the string, rather than try to detect when you have read a score or a name. There is no default implementation of the << operator so either write one for your struct or output the individual fields one at a time.

Comment: I suggest you simplify your code by moving your read function into " struct read_data_into_file ".  This will simplify your code.  Pass in the already opened stream to your function.  Also, replace the array called 'score' with a vector and use push_back() to add values to your scores ... you then do not need to know how big the array is at compile time (i.e. a c-style).

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider with your problem. First, you must account for the different amount of scores in each file entry. Also, you have to deal with empty lines in the file.

The code below will make it work for your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void ReadFromFile(){
    std::vector<read_data_into_file> obj;

    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        std::string curLine;
        std::getline(inFile, curLine);

        if (!curLine.size())
            continue;

        std::stringstream curStr(curLine);

        read_data_into_file newObj;
        curStr >> newObj.Fname;
        curStr >> newObj.Lname;

        int i = 0;
        while (curStr.good()) {
            curStr >> newObj.score[i++];
        }

        newObj.sum = 0;
        while (i--) {
            newObj.sum += newObj.score[i];
        }

        obj.push_back(newObj);
    }

    inFile.close();

    for (auto& p : obj) {
        std::cout << p.Fname << " " << p.Lname << " " << p.sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, a proper solution would be to use an `std::vector<double> score;` instead of `double score[5];` in your `read_data_into_file` structure. Then your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct read_data_into_file{
std::string Fname,Lname;
std::vector<double> score;
double sum;
};

void ReadFromFile(){
    std::vector<read_data_into_file> obj;

    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        std::string curLine;
        std::getline(inFile, curLine);

        if (!curLine.size())
            continue;

        std::stringstream curStr(curLine);

        read_data_into_file newObj;
        curStr >> newObj.Fname;
        curStr >> newObj.Lname;

        while (curStr.good()) {
            double curScore;
            curStr >> curScore;
            newObj.score.push_back(curScore);
        }

        newObj.sum = 0;
        for (auto& s : newObj.score)
            newObj.sum += s;

        obj.push_back(newObj);
    }

    inFile.close();

    for (auto& p : obj) {
        std::cout << p.Fname << " " << p.Lname << " " << p.sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, I understand your code. I just want to know what this std::stringstream curStr(curLine); line does in the code. is curStr() a function in string stream?

Comment: I used just to parse each line individually. `curStr` is the name of the `std::stringstream` object used to traverse the elements of the line read.

Comment: in the code that your provided, the sum is going to be the individual sum of the numbers in the line or sum of all the scores?

Comment: The sum will be computed for the numbers on each line, that is, the individual sum. Is not that correct? If you want to sum all the scores you can just add: `double sumAll = 0; for (auto& entry : obj) { sumAll += entry.sum; }`

Comment: I tried to print the sum, it gives me this error Invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'std::vector<double>')